# Visual Studio 2010 only displaying one file at a time

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-io

Suddenly my Visual Studio 2010 is only able to display one file at a time.

Every time I open a new file, it just replaces the current one.

Is it a setting? Is it a bug? Does anybody have a solution for this issue? It's really frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset the settings.

In VS2K8, its there under Tools:-> Import Export Settings:-> Reset all.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your settings in the `Tools > Options > Environment > Documents`

There is an option in there: `Reuse current document window, if saved` and ensure that it is unchecked.